# Given $f(x)=x+\int_{0}^1 t(t+x)f(t) dt $ , what is $f(0) $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, integral-equations

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be such that  $f(x)=x+\int_{0}^1 t(t+x)f(t) dt $ , then how do we find $f(0) $ ?

Comment: 2 years on the site, 200+ questions asked, and you still post questions with no context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=x+\int_{0}^1 t(t+x)f(t) dt=c_1x+c_2  $  where $c_1=1+\int_{0}^1 tf(t) dt $ and $c_2=\int_{0}^1 t^2f(t) dt $.

Put $f$ in the integral and evaluate, you can get a linear system in terms of $c_1$ and $c_2$. Solve it you get an expression of $f$.